# Which version of Java to use

Tags: java, installation

I got a book called "Killer Game Programming in Java" I was supposed to install J2SE 5.0 but J2SE is in End of Life. After some discussion with StackOverflow and the author I installed the updated version from oracle.com, which is JSE 7u5. I downloaded the JDK with the JRE included. So now I am using NetBeans 7.1.2 with JDK 1.7, but the terminal calls it 1.7.0_05. The first program is saying it can't run without a main method. 
  Is there any reason that the updated version I installed might not work with the programs in this book? Is there another recommended version I should try? I posted the full code below. No edits. It comes right from this link *http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch1/ch1.pdf* Any errors are italicized and bold.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  private static final int PWIDTH = 500;   // size of panel
  private static final int PHEIGHT = 400;
private Thread animator;
private boolean running = false;
private boolean gameOver = false;
// more variables, explained later
       :
public GamePanel()
// for the animation
// stops the animation
// for game termination
{
  setBackground(***Color***.white);    // white background
  setPreferredSize( new ***Dimension***(PWIDTH, PHEIGHT));
  // create game components

}  // end of GamePanel()
public void addNotify()
/* Wait for the JPanel to be added to the
   JFrame/JApplet before starting. */
{
  ***super.addNotify();***   // creates the peer
  startGame();         // start the thread
}
private void startGame()
// initialise and start the thread
{
  if (animator == null || !running) {
    ***animator = new Thread(this);***
    animator.start();
  }
} // end of startGame()
public void stopGame()
// called by the user to stop execution
{  running = false;   }
public void run()
/* Repeatedly update, render, sleep */
{
  running = true;
  while(running) {
    gameUpdate();
    ***gameRender();***
    repaint();
try {
// game state is updated
// render to a buffer
// paint with the buffer
Thread.sleep(20);  // sleep a bit
      }
      catch(InterruptedException ex){}
    }
    System.exit(0);   // so enclosing JFrame/JApplet exits
  } // end of run()
  private void gameUpdate()
  { if (!gameOver)
      // update game state ...
  }
  // more methods, explained later...
}  // end of GamePanel class
```

Comment: What do you mean "not compiling"? Could you show the piece of code that doesn't compile?

Comment: Yeah, you should be fine using 7.x.  Perhaps refocus your question about the code and the specific errors you're encountering.

Comment: Without code or error messages... assistance is difficult.

Comment: This code isn't supposed to run, I assume the book takes some basic knowledge of Java as a prerequisite. Cause it is not hard to imagine this code just trying to explain the barebone of a very simple game.

Comment: Do you have `Thread`, `Dimension`, `Color`, etc imported in this file?

Comment: No I don't have any imports. Its right from the authors website though which is why I am now thinking that this is just an example code. The weird thin is that I don't see any import statements in much of the code in this book. I think I'm gonna try emailing the author

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should work with the latest version. Sometimes you may get problems though, because your "old" code uses now reserved keywords. Even when using Java 7 you can set your compiler to use compiling for java 1.5 with `-source 1.5` and `-target 1.5`. However its more likely that you have a different problem than the java compiler version.

Without an error message however your description is too generic for fixing the actual problem.

Comment: The error just says "cannot compile without main method" which is weird because I took it right from the authors website.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I get it. Its not the full code, just an example or a skeleton of code. It's not supposed to run. Its just supposed to help understand.